# verilog code to perform {w=(3*(p+t-1))/t} with look up taples

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, xilinx

I want verilog code to perform  {w=(p+t-1)/t} with look up taples .
The lookup table is to be realized as a ROM 
where:
 p is 3 bits 
t is 2 bits (and not equal to 0)

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: i want know how to do that with look up taple realized as rom

Comment: Do you know how to make a lookup table?

Answer (score 1):

Get a pencil, get a paper. Write down all of the combinations of p and t then calculate w by hand. I'll do one for you...
p=101 t=11
{w=(101+11-1)/11} =>  {w=(5+3-1)/3}  => w=7/3=2.333 = 0b10.0101...

Now do this for all possible inputs
You never specified what kind of signal you need to output so I'll let you think about that.

Then populate a table with all possible outputs and an index. Use logic to find the right output based on the input.

Homework is work and you need to do the work, not me.